# Using SDP to negotiate RTP session for Expo Video

Tags: react-native, expo, sip, rtp, sdp

I'm trying to initialize a SIP-call between a React Native (Expo) app and a SIP device. The media would be sent with RTP. Here's what I have:

- I can send and receive SIP messages between the SIP device and the React Native application, including SDP.
- I have the Expo [Video component](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v46.0.0/sdk/video/) that seems to accept a URI like this for its source: `rtp://192.168.1.16:1234`.

However, [RFC3264](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3264) states that

> The SDP media line defines the port to which the offerer wants to
> RECEIVE the media stream. The IP address and port present in the offer
> indicate nothing about the source IP address and source port of RTP
> and RTCP packets that will be sent by the offerer.

hence the SDP doesn't tell which port to give to the `Video` component. What kind of SDP do should I send from the app to the SIP device and how can I display the received video in React native app?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about React but regarding the SDP to sent, the media line for the RTP audio stream could be for example :

```
m=audio 1234 RTP/AVP 10
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.16
```

It means that audio stream will be sent to host 192.168.1.16 on port 1234 with a static payload type of 10, which is Linear PCM 16-bit Stereo audio. If you have non-static type, then you need an extra attribute line to map the payload, in the form `a=rtpmap:type encoding/clock/channels` ("/channels" being optional).

Comment: Thanks, though since asking I've learnt that my problem is indeed in showing the incoming video on the screen. As far as I understand I can just open a TCP or a UDP port and specify that port in the SDP answer. However, I don't know how to put the incoming video on the screen.

Comment: Yes, but usually RTP is carried by UDP more than TCP. To put the video on screen, i guess you should rely on your graphical framework but you will need to decode RTP frames (unless it's raw video) using an appropriate backend such as ffmpeg or gstreamer for example.

Comment: I asked a new question, updating the phrasing after making some progress. I think the question is sufficiently different to justify a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73990070/3280244