# Raw RTP stream into video in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, rtp

My React Native (Expo) app is receiving a stream of raw RTP bytes into a UDP socket. How can I display the data as a video?

<sub>This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73947206/3280244), now with more accurate phrasing after making some progress.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Do you receive RTP directly in your app? It's not so common use case as user device can be behind the NAT etc.

The common case is:

- use server-side app to get an RTP and convert it to WebRTC (you can use Janus Media Server, GStreamer or something else)
- connect your app to the server via WebRTC and display received video

This approach can solve a lot of issues - NATs, codecs, multiple viewers per RTP stream, recording etc.